# <html:link> tag

Tags: struts

I am new to struts tag libraries. I want to generate an anchor to define a hyperlink destination inside the same document. My code is like this:

```
<html:link anchor="abc" >
            This is to test anchors
</html:link> 

...Some other tags here

<html:link linkName = "abc"  >
           Anchor
</html:link>
```

The error I am getting is `Cannot create rewrite URL: java.net.MalformedURLException: You must specify exactly one of "forward", "href", or "page"`

Can anybody tell me how to solve this?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

as i understand struts and from [apache](http://struts.apache.org/1.2.x/userGuide/struts-html.html#link)

> You must specify exactly one of the action attribute, the forward attribute, the href attribute, the linkName  attribute, or the page attribute.

so in your first tag, i would guess that you would need to add an href tag and the anchor is added on to that. then your tag with linkname should work

that is

```
<html:link href="someurl" anchor="abc" >
            This is to test anchors
</html:link>
```

Comment: But  the hyperlink destination is in the same doccument. so do we still need to specify href?? In html equivalent <a> href = "#abc" we do not specify the url if it is in the same document.how to do it in struts?

Comment: You need to set the href because it's a prerequisite. (or at least one of the attributes specified above). so if it's on the same page, i guess you would set the href="#" and anchor="abc".

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me.
Below is the scenario, in which i got the error.

```
<appl:resource defaultValue="Appl Error" op="GET" category="shunmugaActionMapping" name="specification" property="shunmugaType" id="shunmugaStartMapping" type="string" >
   <td class="<xd:valueOf name="rowStyle"/>">
      <div class="listRowLink"><html:link page="<%=shunmugaStartMapping%>" paramName="specification" paramProperty="routerId" paramId="detailRouterId">&gt; Details</html:link>
      </div>
   </td>
```

This was throwing the following error:

```
servlet E com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper service SRVE0068E: 
Uncaught exception created in one of the service methods of the servlet
/jsp/List.jsp in application Sundaram. Exception created : 
com.ibm.websphere.servlet.error.ServletErrorReport:
javax.servlet.jsp.JspException: Cannot create rewrite URL: 
java.net.MalformedURLException: You must specify exactly one of 
"forward", "href", "page" or "action" 
at org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.handlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:695)
```

All i did is i added the closure at the end:

```
</appl:resource>
```

The problem got solved and I am fine now.

Thanks,
Shunmuga